# How to perform filtering using the query command from plydata, when we are making the comparison with respect to variable with fixed value

Tags: python

In plydata , how shall we be filtering the rows with respect to comparison which we are making with respect to variable whose value is already described

```
lower_age_limit = 10
upper_age_limit = 40

titanic_data >> query('age > {lower_age_limit} & age < {upper_age_limit}')
```

Answer (score 0):

piped query worked

```
titanic_data = (titanic_data >> query(f'age > {lower_age_limit}') >> query(f'age < {upper_age_limit}'))
```